# empty array in params returned when using html 5 "disabled"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-5

when I include the "disabled" attribute, log in as a non-admin and edit an encounter the following code from the update method of my encounters controller returns an empty array for the services_id array in encounter_params .  This causes a problem when the encounter is saved; the services that used to exist get deleted upon saving.  Not good.

```
 <div class="field">
<%= form.collection_check_boxes :service_ids, Service.all, :id, :name, checked: @encounter.service_ids, disabled: !current_user.admin? %>
```

Any idea how I can disallow a non-admin from editing the services in the check boxes but avoid deleting the services upon save?  How can I get the services values from the checkbox back into the encounter_params? or somehow make sure that no service_id params are returned at all (when a non admin edits an encounter)?

Controller's update method:

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @encounter.update(encounter_params)
    value_array = []
    @encounter.goal_assessments.each do |a|
      value_array << a.value
    end
    unless value_array.include?(nil)
      @encounter.status = "Assessed"
      @encounter.save
    end
    format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, notice: 'Encounter was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @encounter }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @encounter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

And here's encounter_params:

```
def encounter_params
  params.require(:encounter).permit(:participant_id, :encounter_date, :recurring, :duration_hours, :status, 
    :encounter_type, :note, :staff_note, work_goal_assessment_attributes: [:goal_id, :value, :id], 
    social_goal_assessment_attributes: [:goal_id, :value, :id], 
    community_goal_assessment_attributes: [:goal_id, :value, :id], service_ids: [])
end
```

[API Dock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box) explains why an empty array is returned (see the "gotcha" section).  Apparently the HTML spec considers unchecked boxes unsuccessful and guides browsers to not send them, so the rails workaround is to insert a hidden field with an unchecked value.  That's where my empty string in the service_ID array in params comes from when I disable its collection_checkbox for non-admins.

Not sure how to work around this though.

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a non-admin user edits an encounter, the collection_checkboxes that contain the service_ids are not editable by design, but rails still returns params that include service_ids => [""] (because of the "gotcha" described in the API dock article above).

I'm using strong params as follows:

```
def encounter_params
  params.require(:encounter).permit(:participant_id, :encounter_date, :recurring, :duration_hours, :status, 
    :encounter_type, :note, :staff_note, work_goal_assessment_attributes: [:goal_id, :value, :id], 
    social_goal_assessment_attributes: [:goal_id, :value, :id], 
    community_goal_assessment_attributes: [:goal_id, :value, :id], service_ids: [])
end
```

Apparently the permit method creates a new hash so you can't edit encounter_params directly and have the edit stick.  So instead, you can edit params[:encounter][:service_ids] like this:

```
if encounter_params[:service_ids] == [""]
  params[:encounter][:service_ids] = nil
end
```

problem solved.